# How to set default boolean value in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to set default boolean value in sequelize?

```js
var Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  flag: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true}
})
Foo.sync().then(() => {
  Foo.create({name: "name"})
})
```

nodejs output:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Incorrect integer value: 'true' for column 'flag' at row 1
```

mysql log:

```
INSERT INTO `foos` (`id`,`name`,`flag`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'name','true','2019-06-27 22:41:25','2019-06-27 22:41:25')
```

Boolean `true` was converted to string '`true`' automatically by sequelize

Environment:

1. mysql version: 5.7.9
2. Sequelize version: 5.8.11
3. Node Version: v8.9.1
4. OS: win10

Answer (score 7):

Most databases define booleans as bits, sequelize-auto defines boolean default values as '0' and '1' when it generates a sequelize model from an existing database table.

So instead of true or false use '1' or '0'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,my code is copy from sequelize official documentation,So now I am very confused why their code can work but I can't

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
sequelize.define('User', { isDeleted: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false } });
```

Note that if you are using SQL then SQL will treat BOOLEAN as a TINYINT

[For more clarificationollow this link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/)

Answer (score -5):

Convert From This

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  flag: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true}
})
```

To This :

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  name:{
     type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, 
     allowNull: false, 
     defaultValue: true
  }
});
```

Comment: you changed the schema in this way